# bootstrap navbar dropdown not working in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage2.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

     <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS for the 'Heroic Features' Template -->
    <link href="css/heroic-features.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">


     </script>

    <title>Online Teacher Appraisal System</title>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.datepick.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            </div>

          <a><div class="navbar-brand"style="color:#ff006e">Name yet to be decided</div></a>
             <div class="navbar-right" style="color:#00ff21">
                <%--<asp:Label CssClass="pull-right" ID="Label_login" runat="server" ></asp:Label></div>--%> 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" >
                       <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <asp:Label CssClass="pull-right" ID="Label_login" runat="server" ></asp:Label></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>        
                          </ul>
                       </li>
                </ul>

            </div>



        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <%--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->--%>
       </div><!-- /.container -->
     </nav> 
         <div class="container">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content1" runat="server"> 
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <div class="jumbotron hero-spacer">   
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content2" runat="server"> 
       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
     </div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Footer" runat="server">
    <footer>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p>Copyright &copy; Aikya Dev Team 2013 </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a master page that will be used for logged in pages, the login name displayed must have a dropdown but i tried this but its not working
 it hovers when i go on to the label but dropdown menu never appears
what is wrong with the code please someone help me on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you check your browser inspection tool, I think you may be having this error:

```
Error("Bootstrap requires jQuery")
```

Bootstrap.js has a jQuery dependency. So you need to load the jQuery first script before bootstrap.js.

this should be the order. right above the `</body>` tab. The path should be relative to where you have placed your file.
NOTE: use /parent_folder/..path_to_your_files

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Hope this helps. :-)